# How can i scan the bar code and qr code via mobile camera?

Tags: android

Hi everyone I am building a android app I need to scan the bar code result can anyone please tell me how can I do this .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to use third party API ZXingscanner.

Comment: ok can you please tell me how can I do this please

Comment: Use google Vision API to scan barcodes. Here u can find complete tutorial & sample https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/bar-codes/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex

Comment: ok i will paste the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your complete solution:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {

        private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
        Button scan_code;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            scan_code = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        }


        public void QrScanner(View view){

            mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
            setContentView(mScannerView);
            mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
            mScannerView.startCamera();         // Start camera
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mScannerView.stopCamera();   // Stop camera on pause
        }

        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result rawResult) {
            // Do something with the result here
            Log.e("handler", rawResult.getText()); // Prints scan results
            Log.e("handler", rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().toString()); // Prints the scan format (qrcode)

            // show the scanner result into dialog box.
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Scan Result");
            builder.setMessage(rawResult.getText());
            AlertDialog alert1 = builder.create();
            alert1.show();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any third party libraries to achieve what you want. [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) is one awesome library you can use.

This code snippet can be used to implement this:

```
public Button.OnClickListener mScan = new Button.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
};

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It requires ZXing barcode app installation, you forgot to mention.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja No. It doesn't

Comment: thanks mam ,let m try

Answer (score 0):

check this ,it may be useful

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-barcode-and-qr-scanner-example/

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/09/android-barcode-scanner-using-zxing.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you need to integrate the zxing library. 
Take a look at the sample code at the  [sample link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162)

Answer (score -1):

Since version 7.8 Google Play Services SDK supports barcode scanning.
Here you can find all info about:
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/08/barcode-detection-in-google-play.html